# Variables with dynamic shape TensorFlow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tflearn

I need to create a matrix in TensorFlow to store some values. The trick is the matrix has to support dynamic shape.

I am trying to do the same I would do in numpy:

```
myVar = tf.Variable(tf.zeros((x,y), validate_shape=False)
```

where `x=(?)` and `y=2`. But this does not work because zeros does not support 'partially known TensorShape', so, How should I do this in TensorFlow?

Comment: Why do you need a dynamic shape? And can't you fix it by using None as shape descriptor?

Comment: Because my matrix depends of the number of samples in the batch, which can change. As far as I know, neither tf.zeros or np.zeros accept a None in the shape.

Comment: Ah, I see. May I ask what you want to do with this matrix??

Comment: Sure. I'am programming a weighted_softmax for semantic segmentation. I want to weight each class by its prior,  so I am calculating the prior of each image when I receive the true labels in the loss function: I need the matrix to store that priors. It would be easier if the loss function could receive additional parameters, so I can compute the priors with Numpy and feed TensorFlow with it, but I don't know any way of doing that.

Answer (score 1):

1) You could use [`tf.fill(dims, value=0.0)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/fill) which works with dynamic shapes.

2) You could use a placeholder for the variable dimension, like e.g.:

```
m = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[])
x = tf.zeros(shape=[m])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(x, feed_dict={m: 5}))
```

Comment: What is the resultant dtype of the `tf.fill(dims, value=0.0)` operation?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the shape out of the session, this could help.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

v = tf.Variable([], validate_shape=False)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(v, feed_dict={v: np.zeros((3,4))}))
    print(sess.run(v, feed_dict={v: np.zeros((2,2))}))
```