# TensorFlow create dynamic shape variable

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need to create a `tf.Variable` with shape which is known only at the execution time.

I simplified my code to the following gist. I need to find in placeholder numbers which is greater than *4* and in the resultant tensor need to *scatter_update* the second item to *24* constant.

```
import tensorflow as tf

def get_variable(my_variable):
    greater_than = tf.greater(my_variable, tf.constant(4))
    result = tf.boolean_mask(my_variable, greater_than)
    # result = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(tf.shape(result)), trainable=False, expected_shape=tf.shape(result), validate_shape=False)   # doesn't work either
    result = tf.get_variable("my_var", shape=tf.shape(my_variable), dtype=tf.int32)
    result = tf.scatter_update(result, [1], 24)
    return result

input = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[5])
    created_variable = get_variable(input)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    result = sess.run(created_variable, feed_dict={input: [2, 7, 4, 6, 9]})
    print(result)
```

I found [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45739125/tensorflow-defining-the-shape-of-a-variable-dynamically-depending-on-the-shap?rq=1) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43263017/variables-with-dynamic-shape-tensorflow) but they have no answers and didn't help me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, stumbled upon the same unanswered questions and managed to piece together a solution for creating a variable with a **dynamic shape at graph creation time**. Note that the shape has to be defined before, or with the first execution of `tf.Session.run(...)`.

```python
import tensorflow as tf

def get_variable(my_variable):
    greater_than = tf.greater(my_variable, tf.constant(4))
    result = tf.boolean_mask(my_variable, greater_than)
    zerofill = tf.fill(tf.shape(my_variable), tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.int32))
    # Initialize
    result = tf.get_variable(
        "my_var", shape=None, validate_shape=False, dtype=tf.int32, initializer=zerofill
    )
    result = tf.scatter_update(result, [1], 24)
    return result

input = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[5])
created_variable = get_variable(input)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    result = sess.run(created_variable, feed_dict={input: [2, 7, 4, 6, 9]})
    print(result)
```

The trick is to create a `tf.Variable` with `shape=None`, `validate_shape=False` and hand over a `tf.Tensor` with unknown shape as initializer.